# Rails why is calling .valid? removing my error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activemodel

Calling `ActiveModel::Validations#valid?` on my `@item` instance is removing my error messages. This is best shown by example.

```
[1] pry(#<ChangeObjectsController>)> @item.errors.add(:new_error, "new error has occurred")
=> ["new error has occurred"]
[2] pry(#<ChangeObjectsController>)> @item.errors.full_messages
=> ["Connection error has occurred", "New error new error has occurred"]
[3] pry(#<ChangeObjectsController>)> @item.valid?
=> true
[4] pry(#<ChangeObjectsController>)> @item.errors.full_messages
=> []
```

In my model class I am including the validation library (**note it does not inherit from** `ActiveRecord::Base`):

```
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
```

The error message is added in this way:
Can anyone provide clarity on this issue? For example, is this desired behavior and I am using it incorrectly?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not in using `pry` gem?

Comment: Yes, to my understanding. For example, when not using pry the behavior is the same. In other words errors do not show as expected. But when I remove the call to valid? errors show as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. It would be inconsistent if `valid?` returned true but there were error messages. You can see in the [rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4642d68d8021893c69bfd16ed6e926ae03a6d777/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L335) that `valid?` explicitly clears the error messages.

The normal way to add error messages is via a validation, either a built in one or a custom one.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful. I was not aware that valid? explicitly clears the error messages.